# Wordpress filter post with dropdown latest and oldest, radio button category and pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, pagination

I have wordpress script

home.php

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main facetwp-template" role="main">

        <?php
        $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
        $blog_has_featured_image = has_post_thumbnail( $page_for_posts );

        $title_chinese = get_field( "title_chinese", $page_for_posts ); 
        $title_english = get_field( "title_english", $page_for_posts ); 
        $description = get_field( "description", $page_for_posts ); 

        if ( $blog_has_featured_image ) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page_for_posts ), 'listable-featured-image' );
            $image = esc_url($image[0]);
        }
        ?>
        <header class="page-header<?php if($blog_has_featured_image) echo ' has-featured-image'; ?>">
            <?php if($blog_has_featured_image): ?><div class="page-header-background" style="background-image: url('<?php echo listable_get_inline_background_image( $image ); ?>')"></div><?php endif; ?>
            <div class="header-content">

                <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo $title_chinese; ?></h1>
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo $title_english; ?></h1>
                <h3 class="page-description"><?php echo $title_english; ?></h3>

                <?php

                    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                    // $posts_per_page = 9;

                    // get all terms in the taxonomy
                    $terms = get_terms( 'category' ); 
                    // convert array of term objects to array of term IDs
                    $term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );

                    if(isset($_GET['sort']) && isset($_GET['post_category']) )
                    {

                        if($_GET['sort'] == 'Latest' && $_GET['post_category'] != 'All')
                        {
                            $order = array('post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $_GET['post_category'],
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'paged'=> $paged, 'orderby'=> 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC'); 
                        }
                        else if($_GET['sort'] == 'Oldest' && $_GET['post_category'] != 'All' ){
                            $order = array('post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $_GET['post_category'],
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'paged'=> $paged, 'orderby'=> 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC');
                        }
                        else if($_GET['sort'] == 'Latest' && $_GET['post_category'] === 'All'){
                            $order = array('post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                        'field' => 'term_id',
                                        'terms' => $term_ids,
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'paged'=> $paged, 'orderby'=> 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC');
                        }  
                        else if($_GET['sort'] == 'Oldest' && $_GET['post_category'] === 'All'){
                            $order = array('post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                        'field' => 'term_id',
                                        'terms' => $term_ids,
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'paged'=> $paged, 'orderby'=> 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC');
                        } 
                    }else{ 
                         $_GET['post_category'] = 'All';
                         $order = array('post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                        'field' => 'term_id',
                                        'terms' => $term_ids,
                                    ),
                                ),
                         'paged'=> $paged, 'orderby'=> 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC'); 
                    }

                    //print_r($order); exit;
                ?>

                <div style="width: 70%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; color: #fff;">
                    <span class="show-me">Show me:</span>
                    <form name="formOrder" method="get" id="formOrder">
                        <select name="sort" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                        <?php $arrays = array('Latest', 'Oldest');
                            foreach($arrays as $a)
                            {
                                echo'<option value="'.$a.'"';
                                if(isset($_GET['sort']))
                                    {
                                        if($a == $_GET['sort'] ){

                                            echo 'selected="selected"';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    echo '>'.$a.'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                      </select>
                    <!-- </form> -->

                    <span class="glance-cat">
                    <?php $categories = get_categories(); if( $categories ): ?>


                        <input type="radio"  onchange="this.form.submit();" name="post_category" value="All" checked="checked"> All
                        <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ): ?>
                            <input  type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit();" name="post_category" value="<?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>" <?php echo ($_GET['post_category']==$category->cat_name)?'checked="checked"':'' ?>><?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </form>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php

                        //if( $categories ):
                        //echo '<ul class="category-list">';

                        //foreach ( $categories as $category ): ?>
                            <!-- <li><a href="<?php //echo esc_sql( get_category_link( $category->cat_ID ) ); ?>"><?php //echo $category->cat_name; ?></a></li>-->
                        <?php //endforeach;

                        //echo '</ul>';
                        //endif; ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>



    <?php 

        //$order['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $query = new WP_Query($order); 

        // Pagination fix
        $temp_query = $wp_query;
        $wp_query   = NULL;
        $wp_query   = $query;

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 

    ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

    <div class="postcards">
        <div class="grid" id="posts-container">
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="grid__item  postcard">
                    <?php

                        /*
                         * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                         */
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'glance' );
                    ?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php 
            //the_posts_navigation();  

            //Custom query loop pagination
            if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) 
            {
                echo '<div class="nav-links">';
                    echo '<div class="nav-next">';
                        previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts', $query->max_num_pages );
                    echo '</div>';

                    echo '<div class="nav-previous">';
                        next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts', $query->max_num_pages );
                        echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            // Reset main query object
            $wp_query = NULL;
            $wp_query = $temp_query;

             wp_reset_query();
        ?>

    </div>

    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

this script is working.

but I need to modify the script.

I want to change if the category radio button click the result back to pagination page 1 with selected category,  when it has already clicked next previous

Can you help me ? I 'm stuck and can't find the solution

thank you.

Comment: why did you comment the form element?

Comment: Sorry i don' have an idea, i paste the tester script. the form element has already type above

Comment: what do you mean by "type above"?

Comment: i edit the script just now, the form element commented already deleted i use <form name="formOrder" method="get" id="formOrder">

Comment: what problem did you encountered?